# How do I list all Amazon Machine Images (AMIs) in a particular region using python boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I need to list all ami's in a particular region, say us-east-1, using boto3. No filters are needed as of now. I just to need to list all the amis. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The important part of this is to specify `self` as the Owner, otherwise you will receive a listing of *every public AMI!*

```
import boto3

# Get a list of all AMIs owned by this account_id
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')

response = client.describe_images(Owners=['self'])

for ami in response['Images']:
  print (ami['ImageId'])  # Or whatever you wish to do
```

See: [`describe_images()` documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_images)

Comment: Yeah I got the solution by myself. Still, thanks for the answer.